# node_modules/rxjs/Rx has no exported member 'merge'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

my component:

```
import {Observable, Subject , merge} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

focus$ = new Subject<string>();
click$ = new Subject<string>();

search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
        const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
        const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
        const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

        return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
            map(term => (term === '' ? states
                : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
        );
}
```

versions:

```
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4"
```

i get error:

> node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'merge'

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-btmk3n?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @Vikas this ```import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';``` with small 'o' solved my problem, thank you so much. if you write it as answer will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) can be used as either a `static` or `instance` method.

for `static` method use
`import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';`

```
 return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
            map(term => (term === '' ? states
                : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
        );
```

for `instance` method use 
`import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';`

```
return Observable.merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
            map(term => (term === '' ? states
                : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
        );
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-btmk3n)**